# Flickering line under background image in Firefox on resize

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, background-image

I'm building a website that has a full width background image in the header that resizes with the page.  There is an unusual flickering horizontal line that appears under the image when it is resized in Firefox.  The line does not appear at full with, but blinks on and off when the size is changed.  The line appears at the bottom of the background image, not the bottom of the header element.

It appears in the MacOS build of Firefox only when I tested it in OSX 10.8.4, Firefox 23.0.  The problem did not appear with Windows 8, Firefox 23.0.1, or in other browsers that I have tested.

Here is the code on my header:

```
<header>
    <h1><span>Sound Soups on Madison - Healthy &amp; Convenient Alternatives for Your Busy Work Week</span><a href="index.php"><img src="images/sound-soups.jpg" id="logo" alt="Sound Soups"></a></h1>
    <nav id="nav-main">
        <?php echo makeLinks($nav1); ?>
    </nav>
</header>


header{
    padding:0 2.12765957% 35px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url('../images/bg-header.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I've tried using cover instead of 100% for the background size, and putting padding or a border under the header.  Googling the problem didn't turn up anything.  Thanks in advance if anyone knows the answer here.

Comment: I had the same problem - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931977/firefox-linux-centos-responsive-design-image-scaling-porblem/21935428#21935428

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:

The issue seems to be related to how FireFox scales the background image. The following seems to fix it for me with FireFox 23.0.1 , OSX 10.8.4

In style.css, try changing the background-size property in the header rule from 100% auto to 99.99% auto, ie

```
header {
background-image: url("../images/bg-header.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 99.99% auto; 
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 2.12766% 35px;
}
```

---

<s>If I'm understanding your question correctly, check the top of the stylesheet @ http://soundsoups.julie-edwards.com/css/responsive.css</s>

You have

```
header{
    background-image:url('../images/none.png');
    padding-bottom:15px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #7a918c;
    margin-bottom:20px;     
}
```

I think the border-bottom is the cause of the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, David. I took out that style and it didn't fix the issue.  It's still flickering in wider screens before going to the responsive styles.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean @Julie , I was looking at the wrong thing. Looks to me like it's something in the way FF handles the background image scaling. If you remove background-size property in the header and replace with something like background-position: bottom right; the line is gone.

Comment: I'm pleased this did the trick for you @Julie . It's an odd FF blip, I don't know if it's a rounding error problem or not, but certainly the first time I've come across it.

Comment: Any clue how to fix this when `background-size` is set to `contain`?

Comment: not off the top of my head @spinningarrow, but if you want to start a jsFiddle I'll be happy to look into it

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa: I have a live example running at http://sahil.me; looks fine on Safari, Chrome, Opera (OS X), but the weird border is there on Firefox.

Comment: @spinningarrow, It seems Firefox doesn't always scale background images correctly and I believe the line you see is actually a 1 px empty space. This fix works for me. In the CSS, add to the HTML selector the rules 'background-color:#fff;' and 'overflow:hidden;' Setting the background colour means you don't see the empty space, and overflow hidden forces this background color to wrap around and under all the contained elements, ie the entire page.

Comment: That worked; thanks!
Is that a known bug in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a background-sized image on the body element.
I fixed it by applying the background-sized image to a positioned div element.

If that can be of any help.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by converting my .jpg background image to a .png.  In case anyone else runs into this and can't change `background-size`, try this.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I have `background-size` set to `contain`.