# Weird border showing around fixed background in FF 34.0

Tags: css, firefox

There's a black solid border showing on the right side of the background image. The border disappears when you resize the window to be shorter than the banner div, and flickers from the right to the left when you resize the window width.

I am using FF 34.0 on OSX Yosemite. This border does not show in FF Developer Edition, or in Chrome.

This is a very <s>tough bug to replicate. It requires a background image taller than its container &</s> the background set to fixed, no repeat. You may need to resize the window to replicate.

Code ([demo](http://totalsolutions.brockettcreative.com/background.cfm)):

```css
[role="banner"] {
  height: 750px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5cHU.jpg') no-repeat  50% 65% fixed transparent;
}
```

```html
<div role="banner" class="clearBoth">
</div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Possibly related:
[Flickering line under background image in Firefox on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423884/flickering-line-under-background-image-in-firefox-on-resize)

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Firefox 34

Comment: Happens to me also (not always but randomly on most pages) in FF after I've updated to 34

Comment: FF31 (Linux) - works. P.S. Why bacon?

Comment: Not able to reproduce in FF 29/ win 7 enterprise sp1

Comment: @knitevision I'm using FF34 (says latest) on Mac 10.10.1, I can check from Linux at home - is v 31 stable on Linux?
I don't want to publish a background image from an unfinished client site, and besides, baconmockup is cool. :)

Comment: @coderMe yea, it works on my Ubuntu. FF 31. Stable version, but surely not latest :)

Comment: Can't replicate on FF 34.0.5 on OS X, can you provide more details on how to replicate?

Comment: Sorry fellas, the JSfiddle quit working at all - does the updated demo work? @Nit

Comment: Still unable to see any problems, regardless of how I resize the window.

Comment: can you at least provide a screenshot? I can't see this.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 34 on Win XP.